# 403s resubmitting a form after login

Tags: django, django-forms

I get a 403 under the following repro steps:

1. While logged out, try to submit a Django form that generates a validation error
2. Log in or signup for a valid account
3. Using the browser, go BACK to the page with the validation error
4. Resubmit the form

Results: 403 error.  This is most likely expected behavior, however I'm looking for a more graceful way to handle this.  Is there a good way to catch this and resubmit the form as the logged in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this question asked in the context of many frameworks, and the only elegant solution is JavaScript.

With JavaScript, you could store the input values in [`localStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). Then on successful form submit event, clear those values. If the form is loaded with those values existing in `localStorage` (the form submission returned 403, and the user went back to the form page), then automatically populate the form with the values.

Its not really that complex to implement, just more work. I believe there are JS libraries based on this idea...

1. Give all your form elements a classname. In the example I will use `store-data`. This can be set in [`forms.Widget.attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) if you define your form in django, or just with the `class` attribute on input elements if you write your own html.
2. On submit, add an item named `formData` to `localStorage`. `formData` is a JS object mapping form field element ids with the classname from above to the element values.
3. If the form is submitted and processed as valid, on the redirect page remove `formData` from `localStorage` with `localStorage.removeItem()`.
4. When loading the form page (this would be where the user went back to the form after a 403), if `formData` exists in `localStorage` then load the values into the form fields.

Here is an example form with this implemented:

```
<form name="myForm" action="{% url 'myapp:form_submit' %}" onsubmit="return storeData()">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" class="store-data" id="inputName" />

    <label>Description: </label>
    <textarea class="store-data" id="textareaDescription"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
function storeData() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("store-data");
    var formData = {};

    // store element ids and values in formData obj
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        formData[elements[i].id] = elements[i].value;
    }

    // store formData to localStorage as string
    localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData));
}

// if the localStorage item has already been set, then the user tried to submit and failed
if (localStorage.getItem('formData')) {
    formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData'))
    // set all the form elements to the values that were stored when the user tried to submit
    for (var key in formData) {
        document.getElementById(key).value = formData[key];
    }
}
</script>
```

And on the redirected success page, be sure to remove the `formData` item. Otherwise, any time the user goes back to the form the values will be loaded into the fields. (I suppose this may be a desired behavior, but I doubt it.)

```
<script>
localStorage.removeItem('formData');
</script>
```

Comment: If you have never worked with `localStorage`, you may wonder why use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`. `localStorage` only stores keys and values as string pairs. Anything added to `localStorage` is converted to string, so it is better practice to convert to string yourself to avoid any surprises.

Comment: It's nice solution, but won't fix exact this issue - if user navigates back and try to submit form from browser history, it will result in 403 http error anyways.

Comment: Ok, actually it won't wix issue with browser back button, but still will improve user experience. I suggest using some existing JS lib for persisting form data (for example, https://github.com/guillaumepotier/garlic.js. Don't forget to use `data-destroy="false"`). Then just navigate user back to form after login and it will be filled with data user provided before and new csrf_token.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is helpful and I'll try it out and let you know it it works.

Comment: I was going to link in Garlic.js, but didn't think it would be helpful. Didn't know you could do the `data-destroy='false'`. But yes, Garlic is the correct answer with that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, it's expected behaviour. When you login, new [csrf_token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/) is generated. And when you navigate back to page with validation error, it still contains old csrf_token in `<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="old_token" />`. So you submit form with invalid csrf_token and get 403 error.

I can suggest two options for you (none of them I like)

1. Disable new csrf_token generation on login. Just place `request.META['CSRF_COOKIE_USED'] = False` after `login(request, user)` in your loggin view.
2. Disable csrf protection [via decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) for your single view, or globally by removing [csrf middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it) from your settings.py.

Comment: What are the downsides of option 1?  Not a fan of option 2 because I see this error happening on multiple pages.

Comment: Disabling CSRF protection is not a solution. See my answer to store the form data with JavaScript.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28081887/3343740

Comment: @davko both solutions have security issues. First one is IMO better than disabling csrf at all. You can apply second solution to multiple pages by disabling csrf protection globally (remove middleware from settings), but I won't recomend doing it.